# The least upper bound of $|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2|$

Tags: inequality, optimization, complex-numbers

For $j=1,\cdots n$, let $a_j\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ and $|a_j|<n$.

If $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j=n(n-1)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1-a_j}=0$, what is the least upper bound of $|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2|$?

Note $|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2|\le\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_j|^2<n^3$.

I tried the case when $n=3$. Then $\sum_{j=1}^{3}a_j^2=(\sum_{j=1}^{3}a_j)^2-2(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)=18$, because $\sum_{j=1}^{3}a_j=6$ and $a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3=9$ from $\sum_{j=1}^{3}\frac{1}{1-a_j}=0$.

But I have no idea to find the least upper bound for $n\ge 4$. Any suggestions? Thanks